# React — componentDidUpdate as a promise/callback. Is it possible?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a class method I use to update a component's state. I want the method to return a promise which resolves when the component has updated. The method I intend to use for updating my components state will only be called during very specific circumstances, thus the conventional way of using `componentDidUpdate` will only make things extremely convoluted.

Some pseudo:

```
addItems(newItems) {

  this.setState({items: [...this.state.items, ...newItems]});

  return new Promise(resolve => {
    this.componentDidUpdate(() => resolve());
  });

}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to clutter `componentDidUpdate`, you can use the setState callback which gets called after state is updated and re-rendering. Obviously its recommended to have such logic in `componentDidUpdate`.

```
this.setState({items: [...this.state.items, ...newItems]},function(){
    //gets called after state update and re-rendering.
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have an unresolved promise that `componentDidUpdate` resolves and then replaces with a new one. Then, in `addItems`, you wait for the current update promise to resolve. One advantage of this is that if you have multiple places in the code that need to be notified when the update happens, they can all use the same promise. (You could also do it with an array of callbacks you add to and then `componentDidUpdate` notifies, but...that's basically what the promise does, and if it's a promise you can use the various promise composition patterns, etc., if needed.)

Add a method:

```
createUpdatePromise() {
    this.updatePromise = new Promise(resolve => {
        this.resolveUpdatePromise = resolve;
    });
}
```

Call it from your constructor.

Then, in `componentDidUpdate`:

```
this.resolveUpdatePromise();
this.createUpdatePromise();
```

`addItems`:

```
addItems(newItems) {
  this.setState({items: [...this.state.items, ...newItems]});

  this.updatePromise()
  .then(() => {
    // Updated
  });
}
```